# Unable to type in an input field when adding item to cart in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The logic I'm try to apply here may be totally wrong. This is the first time I'm
attempting to do something like this (trying to use an input field to get value of the number of items to be added to cart). I'm not able to type in the input field.

```
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)
    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(e.target.value <=product.countInStock && e.target.value > 0){
                setQty(e.target.value)
                history.push(`/cart/${match.params.id}?qty=${qty}`)
        }else{
            alert("Insifficient Quantity in Stock")
            }
    }
========================================
<Row>
    <Col sm={4}>Qty</Col>
    <Col sm={8}>
    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Control
            type="number"
            min="0"
            max={product.countInStock} 
            value={qty}
            onchange={checkInput}                                                         
            />
        <Button
               onClick={addToCartHandler}
                size="lg"
                disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                type='button'>
                Add to Cart
             </Button>

         </Form>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

How do I fix it? It seems to be a popular issue that people have asked question on online but still can't find solution to mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem with your event handlers. Since you pass the `value={qty}` to the input field, you create a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). However upon updating the input you don't update the parent's state, so in the end the input's value doesn't change.

Try something like this on your input:

```
<Form.Control
    type="number"
    min={0}
    max={product.countInStock}
    value={qty}
    onchange={(e) => setQty(e)}/>
```

*(I assume the onChange returns the new value as number. If it doesn't, you'll need to transform the returned data accordingly before checking it in the submit event handler.)*

Also update the `submitHandler` to be:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (qty <= product.countInStock && qty > 0) {
        history.push(`/cart/${match.params.id}?qty=${qty}`)
    } else {
        alert('Insufficient Quantity in Stock')
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `onchange={(e) => setQty(e)}` will set the state variable to the event object, not the value of the input field in question.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the clarification. Still finding difficulty getting the code work as I want. Still having difficulty getting `qty` in history.push.

Comment: That's, I can't get the current value of qty

Comment: As it is now, when I click on add to cart, I get the initial start of qty (that's 1). The quantity I input doesn't update the state.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is correct in that a controlled input field won't change its value unless you change the state variable that controls it. So really what you need is to put `setQty(e.target.value)` inside your `checkInput` function. That should do the trick.

You could also use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to control your form. That way there won't be a need to rerender your elements every time there is a change in the input field. Let me know if you're interested to see how that would look in your case.

Comment: Thanks @codemonkey I want to know how it looks like. I want a situation whereby I can get the current value of qty so that I can use `history.push` in the submit handler

Comment: Also, when I replaced setQty(e) with setQty(e.target.value) I didn't see any difference. The state isn't updated still

Comment: @C-Bizz Show the rest of your code. Where is your `checkInput` function? Also note that you should use `onChange`, not `onchange`.

Comment: Thank you @codemonkey I have fixed it, just little mistake on my part